# Calling external RPC method from OCW

Tags: offchain-worker, json-rpc

I want to call an external RPC method from the `offchain_worker`. I checked multiple jsonrpc clients but none of them were `no_std` compatible. I want to know if there are any clients out there which can be used within the ocw of `substrate`.

I also tried to call the RPCs using `sp_runtime::offchain::http::Request`, but couldn't find an example of `post` method, any examples/help would be much appreciated.

---

[EDIT]
just found an example of the latter part [here](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/offchain-http-requests/#read-and-submit-the-response), so please just let me know if there are `no_std` jsonrpc clients out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like there's no RPC client ATM which supports `no_std`.
the following is the implementation of an RPC method using `sp_runtime::offchain::http::Request` and `serde`:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use scale_info::prelude::string::String;
use sp_runtime::{
  offchain::{
    http::Request,
    Duration,    
  },
};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct RpcObject {
  jsonrpc: String,
  method: String,
  params: String, // could be a nested object
  id: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct RpcResponse {
  result: String,
  id: String
}

fn call_rpc_method(url: &str, method: String, params: String) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error<T>> {
    let request_body = RpcObject {
      jsonrpc: String::from("2.0"),
      method: method.into(),
      params: params.into(),
      id: String::from("1")
    };
    let request_body_str = serde_json::to_string(&request_body).map_err(|_| <Error<T>>::Error)?;
    let request = Request::post(url, vec![request_body_str.clone()])
      .add_header("content-type", "application/json");

    let timeout = sp_io::offchain::timestamp()
      .add(Duration::from_millis(FETCH_TIMEOUT_PERIOD));

    let pending = request
      .deadline(timeout)
      .body(vec![request_body_str.clone()])
      .send() // Sending the request out by the host
      .map_err(|e| {
        log::error!("rpc request err: {:?}", e);
        <Error<T>>::Error
      })?;

    let response = pending
      .try_wait(timeout)
      .map_err(|e| {
        log::error!("rpc error: {:?}", e);
        <Error<T>>::HttpFetchingError
      })?
      .map_err(|e| {
        log::error!("rpc error: {:?}", e);
        <Error<T>>::HttpFetchingError
      })?;

    if response.code != 200 {
      log::error!("Unexpected http request status code: {}", response.code);
      return Err(<Error<T>>::HttpFetchingError);
    }

    // Next we fully read the response body and collect it to a vector of bytes.
    let resp_bytes = response.body().collect::<Vec<u8>>();
    Ok(resp_bytes)
  }
```

next you can use the response like:

```rust
let resut: RpcResponse = serde_json::from_slice(&res)
            .map_err(|e| {
              log::info!("deserialize error: {:?}", e);
              <Error<T>>::DeserializeToObjError
            })?;
```